# How can i get my geolocation with longitude and latitude?

Tags: java, android

so i want to create a method to get my geolocation **(longitude and latitude)**, i don't need to display the result in a map i just want the 2 parameters **(longitude and latitude)**, so please if someone have any idea i will be very appreciate.
NB:I live in **Morocco**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make sure you have the following permission defined in the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name=“android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION”/>
```

Then define a `LocationManager` and assign a listener to it:

```
LocationManager mlocManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

LocationListener mlocListener = new MyLocationListener();

mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mlocListener);
```

The listener should then be able to receive coordinates.

You can define a listener like this:

```
public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener 
{

     @Override

     public void onLocationChanged(Location loc)
     {
        float latitude = loc.getLatitude(); //Retrieve the latitude
        float longitude = loc.getLongitude(); //Retrieve the longitude
        Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(),"Current location: "+latitude+","+longitude,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thnx **Leon**, but my question it how to get latitude and longitude without knowing the location, in other words to get my position like **GPS**.

Comment: I don't really get what you are trying to ask here, because the above code retrieves the coordinates from the GPS.

Comment: Thanks to reply me, i am really appreciate that, but in the method **onLocationChanged(Location loc)** the parameter loc it should me to give it right, but what i am looking for it to get Latitude and longitude without define the location,

Comment: It's a listener class, you don't call the method yourself. The `onLocationChanged(Location loc)` method gets called by the LocationManager when the GPS reports a new location. I've added a Toast to the example so you can check this.